# When should field_attach_load be called manually?

Tags: 7, caching, entities

I'm trying to use the module [ClosedQuestion](http://drupal.org/project/closedquestion) together with [EntityCache](http://drupal.org/project/entitycache).
When I enable EntityCache, then the fields on my CQ nodes becomes duplicated. I believe the cause is that both EntityCache, and ClosedQuestion, calls field_attach_load on the nodes.

There's a specific issue [here](http://drupal.org/node/1415100), about this problem, but I'm looking for more general information, about what is the *intended* usage of field_attach_load? I've never seen a module doing it manually before, and don't think it's supposed to be used [like this](http://drupalcode.org/project/closedquestion.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-2.x:/closedquestion.module#l410).

Comment: If you're looking for an example, I wrote a "casetracker" like module for D7 that added a Node's fields to the comment form. In that case, I also used `field_attach_submit` to save those fields too! It actually worked pretty well. [here's the source](http://drupalcode.org/sandbox/jrowny/1281972.git/blob/refs/heads/master:/cne.module)

Comment: Your using `field_attach_form` there, right? Still that's interesting, the use-cases should be similar. Your suggestion gave me the idea to grep for field_attach_load in other contrib modules. I only found it in media, which uses it to create dummy content during upgrade. While this doesn't really tell me anything definite, it certainly leans towards, "Using it for loading the node, is wrong".

Comment: Yes, sorry, sometimes you read what is familiar! I've never used `form_attach_load`, but it does indeed look similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[api.drupal.org](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--field--field.attach.inc/function/field_attach_load/7) says:

> field_attach_load() is automatically called by the default entity
>   controller class, and thus, in most cases, doesn't need to be
>   explicitly called by the entity type module.

Basically only call it if you're implementing an entity type and don't want to use the default entity controller. I'm pretty sure ClosedQuestion is in the wrong, since it's only making a node type. All fields should be attached by the time `hook_load()` comes along.